# Generating replacement text from found text for Word addin, using VB.NET and Office-Interop

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I need to add correct stress accents to every word in a Microsoft Word document.  I have a script called "DoAccentuate" which determines the correct accentuation for any word that is input.  However, I don't know how to capture the currently selected found word, process it with my DoAccentuate script, and replace that same word with the result (without effecting the formatting of the text).  This is what I tried.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim document As Word.Document
    document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument

    Dim FindObject As Word.Find = document.Application.Selection.Find
    With FindObject
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = "<*>"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting()
        .Replacement.Text = DoAccentuate(document.Application.Selection.Text)
        .Execute(Replace:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I would think a better solution would be a one-click approach per document, rather then requiring user to select the word, no? If so, post a new question. It shouldn't be too much programming effort really.

Comment: @jJack thanks for your help!  As you suggest, I'll post a new question for the "one-click" per document scenario.

Comment: feel free to post a link to it from here since its related

Comment: [link to question regarding "one-click" approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15861626/better-method-for-accenting-every-word-in-word-document)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets pretend for now this is your DoAccentuate script:

```
Private Function DoAccentuate(theWordToAccentuate As String)
    theWordToAccentuate = theWordToAccentuate + "`"
    DoAccentuate = theWordToAccentuate
End Function
```

Given this, the find/replace can be as simple as:

```
Public Sub FindWordAndReplaceWithAccentuatedForm()
    Dim accentuatedText As String: accentuatedText = DoAccentuate(Selection.text)

    Selection.Find.text = Selection.text
    Selection.Find.Replacement.text = DoAccentuate(Selection.text)
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

This should not remove any formatting.

I am assuming that you desire a solution which requires user to select the word they want to accentuate, and then run the macro (since your method above assumes this ie: `.Replacement.Text = DoAccentuate(document.Application.Selection.Text`