# better method for accenting every word in Word document?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, office-interop

I am new to programming, but I am trying to adapt an existing script as a MS Word 2010/2013 addin to add correct stress accentuation to every Latin word in an open document.

The script "DoAccentuate" returns an accented word for any unaccented Latin word I send it as a string. I just need help doing a better job of looping through all the words, and then stopping the loop when the last word is reached.  My current method is a bit goofy...I insert a nonesense word at the end of the document and then loop until it gets selected and accented.

Perhaps there's a better or more efficient way to go about the whole thing.

```
    Public Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim document As Word.Document
    document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument
    Dim mySelection = document.Application.Selection
 'make sure cursor is at start of document
      document.Application.Selection.HomeKey(Unit:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdUnits.wdStory)

    'insert fake word at end to stop the loop
    Dim range As Word.Range
    range = document.Range()
    range.InsertAfter(" documentendatoris")

    Do
        'use MS Word's wildcard to select the first individual word as trimmed string
        mySelection.Find.Text = "<*>"
        mySelection.Find.MatchWildcards = True
        mySelection.Find.Execute()
        'replace the selected word that has been found with its accented counterpart
        mySelection.Text = Accentuate.Accentuate.DoAccentuate(mySelection.Text)
    Loop Until mySelection.Text = "documentendatóris"

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this need to support all story ranges in the document? Currently this will not work in Footers, Footnotes, and Endnotes; it will only work in main text story.

Comment: @jJack, it only needs to work in the main text.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't realy know if its more efficient way but you could use ***document.Content*** and ***range.Words*** collection to check all words in main story range

```
    document = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument

    Dim range As Word.Range
    range = document.Content

    Dim current As Integer
    current = 0

    Dim words As Word.Words
    words = range.Words

    Dim word As Word.Range

    Do
        current = current + 1
        If current < words.Count Then
            word = words(current)
            If word.Text.EndsWith(" ") Then
                word.Text = word.Text.Trim() + "'s "
                'replace the selected word that has been found with its accented counterpart
                'mySelection.Text = Accentuate.Accentuate.DoAccentuate(mySelection.Text)
            Else
                word.Text = word.Text.Trim() + "'s"
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until current = words.Count
```

Comment: I think 'more efficient' was in terms of the user experience, since the previous solution was to have user explicitly select each word to accentuate. Your solution looks good.

Comment: @johhoso since you didn't accept tinamou's answer can you explain the gap?